# Validating json with jsonschema and robotframework

Tags: json, robotframework, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

Can anyone help get me started on how to use RobotFramework to validate json responses via a json-schema?

Ideally, the json-schema is externally referenced via an http request: Example http://api-bl-uk.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/v1/crm/schemas/contact

Progress so far:

```
pip install robotframework
pip install robotframework-jsonvalidator
pip install robotframework-jsonschemalibrary
robot .\mytest.robot
```

Where `mytest.robot` is:

```
Library JsonValidator
Library JSONSchemaLibrary schemas
*** Test Cases ***
  My Test Case:
   Validate Json  service.schema.json  {"foo": "bar"}
```

I have a schema in the subdirectory `schemas` called `service.json`

When I run the test I get...

```
$ robot .\mytest.robot
==============================================================================
Mytest
==============================================================================
My Test Case:                                                         | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'Validate Json' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mytest                                                                | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  E:\GitLab\customer-api\test\output.xml
Log:     E:\GitLab\customer-api\test\log.html
Report:  E:\GitLab\customer-api\test\report.html
```

So it seems I'm missing a fairly basic piece of the puzzle:

**No keyword with name 'Validate Json' found**

## UPDATE

The problems of blindly following 'sample code'

The problem was I was missing the `*** Settings ***` header prior to the `Library` statements, plus the name of the schema to use was wrong (easy to solve after the header was fixed).

Full example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  JSONSchemaLibrary  schemas

*** Test Cases ***
My Test Case:
    Validate Json  service.json  {"foo": "bar"}
```

Now... How do I use external referenced schema files?  The quest continues!

:)

Comment: Are you certain that the JSONSchemaLibrary has a keyword named "validate json"? Is JSONSchemaLibrary an actual robot framework keyword library, or is it just a python module?

Comment: @BryanOakley - TBH, I'm a total newb at robotframework and python so my answer is, I don't know! I've done some googling but the results are disappointingly sparse.

At this time, I'd just be happy to get a 'json schema validation failed' error message back - at least then I know that I've got the modules / libraries all setup right.

My test is based on:  https://github.com/jstaffans/robotframework-jsonschemalibrary

Comment: Try with the import of `JsonValidator` commented  - it has a method `_validate_json`, which might cause a conflict with the method/keyword `validate_json` you're trying to call from the other library. Don't know will that fix it, trying a lucky shot after checking the libs sources.

Comment: @todor - Thanks.  Please see my update to the OP.  Although you didn't directly provide the answer, it did lead me to it by another route. :)

Comment: Case solved, that's the important part :) BTW if I were you, I'd delete the first part of the question (it was a simple syntax typo), thus not diluting it, and allowing anyone knowledgeable in the libraries concentrate on the remaining issue.

Comment: For the second question - please provide a sample of your framework's directory structure, plus your cwd when you run the tests. The library gets the schemas directory as given - relative or absolute path, and does some unorthodox (for python) concatenation [of the file name to it](https://github.com/jstaffans/robotframework-jsonschemalibrary/blob/master/JSONSchemaLibrary/__init__.py#L31), which might be the culprit of your issue.

Comment: @Todor - Yup, I'm making some progress and will spend some time getting a working example going so this can become a reference piece.   (For me, when I forget next time)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this will work with the library you are using, but I'm using the library `jsonschema` (https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/).

There are two ways I came up with for using a schema from a file. I'd go with the first.

## First way

In your virtualenv, run `pip install jsonschema`.

Then create a new file, `mySchema.json` in the same directory as your test case file. Test case file:

```
*** Settings ***
# For the "Get Binary File" task
Library     OperatingSystem
# For the "validate" task
Library    jsonschema


*** Test Cases ***
Load json schema from file, and validate json
    # Load the file as a string, usually sufficent for most methods, but not validate() below
    ${schema}    Get Binary File    ./mySchema.json
    # Load the string as a binary object, you could then use this like ${schema}[someProperty] if you wanted to
    ${schema}    evaluate    json.loads('''${schema}''')    json
    # Do a simple validation, using the schema, and your json data. Remember ${instance} needs to be a json object, not just some string
    ${instance}    evaluate    json.loads('''{"someField":[1,2,3]}''')    json
    validate    instance=${instance}    schema=${schema}
```

## Second way

In your virtualenv, run `pip install jsonschema`.

Then create a new file, `mySchema.json` in the same directory as your test case file. Test case file:

```
*** Settings ***
# For the "Get Binary File" task
Library     OperatingSystem
# For the "validate" task
Library    jsonschema


*** Test Cases ***
Load json schema from file, and validate
    # Create a schema
    ${schema}    concat
    ... {
    ...   "type": "object",
    ...   "properties": {"$ref": "file:/absolute/path/to/mySchema.json"}
    ... }
    ${schema}    evaluate    json.loads('''${schema}''')    json
    # Do a simple validation, using the schema, and your json data. Remember ${instance} needs to be a json object, not just some string
    ${instance}    evaluate    json.loads('''{"someField":[1,2,3]}''')    json
    validate    instance=${instance}    schema=${schema}
```

If you want to get the schema file from an external source, have a look at the requests library. Something like:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     RequestsLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Test case
    Create Session    yourSession    http://localhost
    ${file}    Get Request    yourSession    /filename
```